# Cannot plot 2d data in python

Tags: python, scatter-plot

I want to get the plot of 100 data, but this code gives me only 2 dots. Where's the mistake?

```
import random

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

X=np.random.rand(100,2)

plt.scatter(X[0,:],X[1,:],marker='.')
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNhmq.png)

Comment: You may want to try `plt.scatter(X[:, 0],X[:, 1],marker='.')`

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake with `plt.scatter(X[0,:],X[1,:],marker='.')`

`X[:,0]` returns all the x values of the first column

`X[:,1]` returns all the y values of the first column

`X[0,:]` returns all the x values of the first row

`X[1,:]` returns all the y values of the first row

So what you wrote plots the first data point while the following plots the data set:

```
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],marker='.')
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain, why?

Comment: I edited my answer, please let me know if that's clear enough